# Exception in recieving: java.net.SocketException: No such device. in android multicast

Tags: java, android, udp, multicast

I am trying to connect to a multicast group and send udp packets from a server to a client.

i wrote the right permissions on the manifest

the server code:

```
private DatagramSocket datagramSocket;
datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
InetAddress IPAddress;
IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");
DatagramPacket sendPacket;
sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, port);
datagramSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

the client code:

```
private MulticastSocket soketmulNHC;
soketmulNHC = new MulticastSocket(8900);
soketmulNHC = new MulticastSocket(8900);
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
MulticastLock multicastLock = wifi.createMulticastLock("multicastLock");
multicastLock.acquire();
byte[] buffer = new byte[Data.MAX_PACKET_SIZE];             
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");                     
soketmulNHC.joinGroup(group);
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,group,8900);                             
soketmulNHC.receive(receivePacket);
```

and i got this exception:

```
Exception in recieving
java.net.SocketException: No such device
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.setSocketOption(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.setOption(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:198)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:137)
at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:190)
```

i also tried to add the interface part from this link [Multicast - no such device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180275/multicast-no-such-device) and then i got:

```
SocketException in sending: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
```

maybe there is a problem using S2 galaxy for multicasting? 
i need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For most devices (if they have more than one network device), you need to explicitly select which network device should be used for joining the multicast group.